# Category List with custom urls

Tags: categories

How do i get the list of categories as wp_list_categories does but using get_categories and then displaying the links in a foreach loop. The reason is i want the links to point to the current page with [?search-type=normal&s=cat_name; ] instead on pointing to the category url.

This will then filter the results when clicked on the same page.

```
<?php 

            $categories = get_categories(array('hide_empty' => 0, depth => 0, 'hierarchical' => false));

            echo '<ul>';

            foreach($categories as $category) {

                echo '<li><a href="?search-type=normal&s='.$category->term_id.'">'.$category->name.'</a></li>';


                    $sub_categories = get_categories(array('hide_empty' => 0, 'parent' => $category->term_id, 'hierarchical' => true));

                    if(!$sub_categories) {


                    } else {

                         foreach ($sub_categories as $sub_category) {

                             echo '<ul>';
                             echo '<li><a href="?search-type=normal&s='.$sub_category->term_id.'">'.$sub_category->name.'</a></li>';
                             echo '</ul>';
                         }
                    }

            }

            echo '</ul>';
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_categories()` is handy function to get list of categories with all information such as id & name of each category etc.

This code might work. The `$category->term_id` will return the unique id for each category and `$category->name` will return the name to display to user.

```
<?php 
$args=array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC'
  );
$categories=get_categories($args);
foreach($categories as $category) {
echo '<a href="?search-type=normal&s='.$category->term_id.'">'.$category->name.'</a>';
}
?>
```

### Update -

Here is code which uses custom Wordpress [walker class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/Walker_Class) to edit the links. Put this into your themes functions.php

```
 //usage  wp_list_categories( array('walker' => new wpse_59862_walker() ) ) 

class wpse_59862_walker extends Walker_Category {

    // copied function from /inlcude/category-template.php and edited as per requirements
    function start_el( &$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {
        extract($args);

        $cat_name = esc_attr( $category->name );
        $cat_name = apply_filters( 'list_cats', $cat_name, $category );
        $my_blog_link = site_url('/'); //this is to return blog url

        //here I edited the link to meet your requirments.
        $link = '<a href="'.$my_blog_link.'?search-type=normal&s='.$category->term_id.'" ';

        if ( $use_desc_for_title == 0 || empty($category->description) )
            $link .= 'title="' . esc_attr( sprintf(__( 'View all posts filed under %s' ), $cat_name) ) . '"';
        else
            $link .= 'title="' . esc_attr( strip_tags( apply_filters( 'category_description', $category->description, $category ) ) ) . '"';
        $link .= '>';
        $link .= $cat_name . '</a>';

        if ( !empty($feed_image) || !empty($feed) ) {
            $link .= ' ';

            if ( empty($feed_image) )
                $link .= '(';

            $link .= '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_feed_link( $category->term_id, $category->taxonomy, $feed_type ) ) . '"';

            if ( empty($feed) ) {
                $alt = ' alt="' . sprintf(__( 'Feed for all posts filed under %s' ), $cat_name ) . '"';
            } else {
                $title = ' title="' . $feed . '"';
                $alt = ' alt="' . $feed . '"';
                $name = $feed;
                $link .= $title;
            }

            $link .= '>';

            if ( empty($feed_image) )
                $link .= $name;
            else
                $link .= "<img src='$feed_image'$alt$title" . ' />';

            $link .= '</a>';

            if ( empty($feed_image) )
                $link .= ')';
        }

        if ( !empty($show_count) )
            $link .= ' (' . intval($category->count) . ')';

        if ( 'list' == $args['style'] ) {
            $output .= "\t<li";
            $class = 'cat-item cat-item-' . $category->term_id;
            if ( !empty($current_category) ) {
                $_current_category = get_term( $current_category, $category->taxonomy );
                if ( $category->term_id == $current_category )
                    $class .=  ' current-cat';
                elseif ( $category->term_id == $_current_category->parent )
                    $class .=  ' current-cat-parent';
            }
            $output .=  ' class="' . $class . '"';
            $output .= ">$link\n";
        } else {
            $output .= "\t$link<br />\n";
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @amit, however, would like to be able to display the parent and child relationship aswell. I can display all categories fine as <li> but i want to add <li>Parent<ul><li>Child</li></ul></li>

Comment: is the code you are updated in question is working or not ?

Comment: hey, I'd use `wp_list_categories()` instead using `get_categories()` to list categories and use a action hook to replace the url. that'd be lot easier.

Comment: Ok, thnaks @amit for your assistance, if you could show me how i would write the action hook to replace the url, i would so much appreciate it. I'm still new to Wordpress and 'm still getting my head around filters,hooks, add_action and so forth.

Comment: updated answer with new code which uses wordpress walker class to edit the links